# Why is my img ontop of my script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I̶'̶m̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶r̶o̶u̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶i̶m̶g̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶o̶p̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶s̶c̶r̶i̶p̶t̶.̶
New Problem the script is stuck to the side instead of the whole page      (still a beginner)

It's a particle-js script i want to be the whole page background and the img to be center and on in on top of particles.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #1b1b1b
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img class="img" src="./img/Biohazard.png" alt="13" align="center">
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/particles.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Something's wrong with your question. Do you know what's a script?

Comment: java script question mark i'm learning still

Comment: You say the script is stuck on the side instead of the whole page. this makes no sense. You say your img is on top of your script but a script isn't a visual element.

Answer (score -2):

You just write a typo attribute instead of **class** you type **claas**